# How to show/hide tr if there td's have same value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to do show/hide only those tr if there last 2 td have same text.in this table i want to 3rd tr and 4th tr show hide. its have same value.

```
<table  class="table table-zeroBorder sticky-table vrt_table" id="tabledata">
   <thead >
      <th >&nbsp;</th>
   
      <th "> Alto STD </th>
      <th > Alto LXI </th>
   </thead>
   <tbody >
     
      <tr >
         <td >Wheel Covers</td>
         
         <td>
             Center Cap
         </td>
         <td >
            Full
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
         <td >Body Coloured Bumpers</td>
         
         <td >
          - 
         </td>
         <td >
            yes
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
         <td>Body Coloured Outside Door Handles </td>
        
         <td >
             yes 
         </td>
         <td >
            yes
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td >Body Side Molding</td>
        
         <td >
             - 
         </td>
         <td >
             - 
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
         <td >High-Mounted Stop Lamp</td>
         
         <td >
             yes
         </td>
         <td >
          
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My jquery code here.this jquery code hide all tr which have '-' value . in this table i want to 3rd tr and 4th tr show hide. its have same value.

```
$("#tabledata tbody tr td:contains('" + '-' + "')").filter(function () {
      return $(this).text().trim() == '-';
    }).parent().toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to iterate all the `<tr>` elements, check the `<td>` contents and toggle visibility accordingly

```js
$("#hide-rows").on("click", () => { 
  $("#tabledata tbody tr").each((_, tr) => {
    // Wrap the <tr> in a jQuery object
    const $tr = $(tr)

    // get the last two <td> children
    const cells = $tr.find("td").slice(-2)

    // get all the unique values
    const values = new Set(cells.map((_, { textContent }) =>
      textContent.trim()).get())

    // Toggle the <tr>
    $tr.toggle(values.size === 1)
    
    // or without using a Set
    // $tr.toggle(cells.eq(0).text().trim() === cells.eq(1).text().trim())    
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tabledata"> <thead > <th >&nbsp;</th> <th> Alto STD </th> <th > Alto LXI </th> </thead> <tbody > <tr > <td >Wheel Covers</td><td> Center Cap </td><td > Full </td></tr><tr > <td >Body Coloured Bumpers</td><td > - </td><td > yes </td></tr><tr > <td>Body Coloured Outside Door Handles </td><td > yes </td><td > yes </td></tr><tr> <td >Body Side Molding</td><td > - </td><td > - </td></tr><tr > <td >High-Mounted Stop Lamp</td><td > yes </td><td > </td></tr></tbody></table>

<p><button id="hide-rows" type="button">Hide rows</button></p>
```